# Relationship between the dimension of a subspace of $R^n$ and $n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Apologies if this is an obvious question, but I am unsure of myself. Suppose we have a subspace $S$ of $R^n$. It is true then that dim $S \leq$ $n$?

Comment: Yes.  Also, more words to hit the 15 character limit.  Also, yes.

Comment: @XanderHenderson don't you just hate that

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is the definition of dimension of a space that you are using?

If it's "the largest number of vectors in the space that are linearly independent", the inequality is pretty clear.

If it's "the smallest number of vectors that generates the subspace", it's not something right away obvious.

Both definitions are equivalent, and that is a theorem. So, YES.

Answer (score 1):

The same question, but perhaps easier to see: Can you have $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$ dimensional space?